# Using Crystal Reports XI with classic asp

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, crystal-reports-xi

I am trying to use Crystal Reports XI for viewing/edits reports in classic ASP. I run into following error on this line :

```
Set session ("oApp") = Server.CreateObject("CrystalRuntime.Application")
```

Error:

> Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'
>
> Server.CreateObject Failed

I went through all the solutions found online but couldnt find resolution.

I am using IIS7.

Please help.

Comment: Try `Server.CreateObject("CrystalRuntime.Application.11")`

Answer (score 0):

There are many DLL's that have to be registered. The easiest way is to install the runtime libraries from SAP (the makers of Crystal Reports).  You can find them on the SAP website. Don't have an exact address for you as they don't make it real easy to find. If I find it, I'll update my answer.

Also, the version number is not required unless you have more than one version installed and want to use less than the latest version. Otherwise Server.CreateObject("CrystalRuntime.Application") will automatically use the newest version installed.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to register the DLL's, however it is complex to register these manually as some of the DLL's have dependencies and you will have to register them in a particular order.

Rather install the runtime libraries, the following link has links on how to get the runtime libraries for old versions of Crystal Reports and Xcelsius

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-27613