# migrating to crystal report 11 in classic asp

Tags: asp-classic, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-8.5

I have a website developed in Classic ASP that uses Crystal report viewer to display reports.
It uses an older version (8.5) while I am moving it to Windows Server 2012 having crystal report 11.

Following is the report viewer used:

On execution of following line:

`Set session("oApp") = Server.CreateObject("CrystalRuntime.Application")`

I get following error:

Server object error 'ASP 0177 : 800401f3'

Server.CreateObject Failed

/CrystalReports/HRReporting/ParameterField.asp, line 10

800401f3

I referred:
[Using Crystal Reports XI with classic asp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779990/using-crystal-reports-xi-with-classic-asp)

but didn't get any solution

Kindly help me in knowing what changes I need to make in code and DLLs I need to register and in what order?

Comment: i got an alternate of using an aspx page instead of asp page and called the aspx page with crystal report viewer from the asp page.

Comment: I have to do something similar, did you just use a single aspx page to do this then?